# Last child not removing border bottom

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="offer-section">
    <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
<div class="offer-section">
    <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
<div class="offer-section">
    <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
<div class="offer-section">
    <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.offer-section{
   .divider { border: solid 1px #bdbdc3; height: 2px; margin-top: 5%; }
}
.offer-section:last-child {
   .divider { }
}
```

Trying to add a divider to the bottom of every offer-section div except the last one. However the code above does not seem to be able to do the job. Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Where are you testing this? In a JSFiddle or something similar? This will work, and it should - unless you have another child *after* the last `.offer-section` (which would make that element the last child and not the last `.offer-section`). Also, just for the sake of demonstration and clarity, better to stick with standard CSS syntax in such situations rather than LESS/SASS syntax (if you are using this a preprocessor and need to display the syntax as such for any reason don't forget to include the relevant tags as the issue may be related to those frameworks)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide proper CSS properties as per the requirement, as given below.

```
.offer-section{
  .divider { border: solid 1px #bdbdc3; height: 2px; margin-top: 5%; }
}
.offer-section:last-child {
  .divider { border: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.offer-section .divider {
    border: solid 1px #bdbdc3; height: 20px; margin-top: 5%;
}
.offer-section:nth-child(4) .divider{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```